# Understand Cloud Firestore billing

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question because I don't want a $30k bill.

Is this an acceptable code to work with, or is there a better way?

I am using firebase 8.10.0 with Vue.js 2.6.11 and I created the index in firestore.

If there are 1000 documents in the collection "users" and I need to apply filters in the query before making the request for only 50 using this code:

```
let users = db.collection("users");

users
.where("country" "==" "uk")
.where("online" "==" true)
.where("status" "==" "play")
.orderBy("time", "asc")
.startAt(startTime)
.endAt(endTime)
.limit(50)
.get().then(() => { .... });
```

Will I be charged for 50 readings or 1000 readings or how much?

What do they mean by "Cursors" in [Understand Cloud Firestore billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing)?

Comment: I think you'll only be billed for 50 reads here, but don't stake your budget on that. I'm trying to extrapolate from how the Realtime Database works and from my own limited understanding even of that.

Comment: This question is not bad, but it seems to fall off the scope of StackOverflow, which answers code-specific questions. You'd probably be better of contacting Firebase support. (To give you some hope, I once emailed Firebase and they replied me in 2 hours, so yay.)

Comment: I disagree that this is off-topic; this question is code-specific, i.e. "if I run this code, how many reads are gonna happen". Using the language of the [off-topic FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), this question covers both a commonly used tool and a practical and answerable problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are charged for the number of documents that need to be read from the server. Since you only read at most 50 documents, you will never be charged for more than 50 document reads with this query. No matter if the collection has 50 documents, or 50 million documents, the charge for this query will be no more than 50 document reads.

The only exception to this general rule is if the query has no results. In that case you will be charged one document read.

Comment: What if I don't use ```.limit(50)``` and the results return 100 documents , I be charged for 100 readings?

Comment: and is ```startAt(time)``` and  ```endAt(time)``` an offset?

Comment: **You are charged for the number of documents that need to be read from the server.** So if you read 100 documents, you may be charged for 100 reads indeed. --- Firestore pagination is based on query cursors, not on offsets, so `startAt` and `endAt` are not offsets, but actual field values. I recommend reading https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors